# How to get number of messages in one topic from rosbag.py

Tags: python, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I was wondering whether with the Python module rosbag there is any chance to get the number of recorded messages in one topic. The Bag.read_messages method returns a generator and of course I could iterate over all messages and count. But is there a way to tell the number in advance? That way I could preallocate the right amount of lists to handle the messages.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195811/how-to-get-number-of-messages-in-one-topic-from-rosbag.py/) by [odelay](https://answers.ros.org/users/20568/odelay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosbag python module has several ways to count the number of messages in a rosbag file. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a public API, you often have to just read the comments in the [code](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/tools/rosbag/src/rosbag/bag.py).

To get the total number of messages:

```
bag.get_message_count()
```

You can also filter for a specific topic name

```
bag.get_message_count('/tf')
```

will count the number of messages on the '/tf' topic. Note this is the topic name, not the message type.

---

If you want slightly more information, you can use

```
bag.get_type_and_topic_info().topics
```

and you will get a whole lot more information, including the number of messages per topic, the frequency, etc...

```
{'/joint_states': TopicTuple(msg_type='sensor_msgs/JointState', message_count=2500, connections=1, frequency=500.99187768752984),
 '/rosout': TopicTuple(msg_type='rosgraph_msgs/Log', message_count=35, connections=1, frequency=67108.864),
 '/tf': TopicTuple(msg_type='tf2_msgs/TFMessage', message_count=7697, connections=1, frequency=32768.0)}
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) with karma: 539 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7